# Copying Conditional formatting (rule by formula)

Tags: excel

I got a tricky question.
In a workbook, F32:L500 are just numeric values (monthly figures), while N32:S:500 are values determined by the corresponding value from F32:L500 (take a cell q100 as example, the corresponding cell will be I100)

1. If i100>=0, q100=i100 and the cell will not be filled
2. If i100<0 and h100=0, q100=0, q100 will be filled with purple
3. If i100<0 and h100>0, q100=0 and p100=h100+i100, q100 will be filled with purple wile p100 will be filled with pink.

I tried use conditional formatting (rule by formula) and copy formatting by paste special, but it didn't work as the reference cells won't change as I expected. (All formatting in N32:S500 reference f32 and g32 as they are all copied) I want to avoid that? What can I do?

Comment: Post a picture if you can. With the information you shared, it seems you are running into absolute reference. Enter formula edit mode and remove the "$" absolute reference character. The new cells will stop referencing the cells you copied the formula from. If this helped you, let me know.